# How to set a domain to ip address and port deploy Spring boot app in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, webserver

I have VPS with Ubuntu 20.04. I have run a Spring boot Web app in Docker on port 8090. Right now, the website work only with ip address, example

```
http://12.12.12.12:8090
```

It's good.
But not with domain name.

I have domain

```
firstapp.example.com
```

I have redirected the domain name to my server's IP address. And I don't know what next. I need add someting in `appication.properties` or change sometiong in apache2?

I have created a new file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/firstapp.example.com.conf
```

and added

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
        ServerName firstapp.example.com
        ServerAlias www.firstapp.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/app/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

but it's only give access by `12.12.12.12:8090` to directory.

Comment: i think you should use a reverse proxy(nginx, apache, ...) to listen on 80 or 443 port from the nameserver(firstapp.example.com) and distribute request  to your local port (8090)

Comment: it's not part of your program, there are multi solution, you run your spring boot application in your VPS, then config your reverse proxy, are you sure that domain is binded to your VPS ?

Comment: yes, I've checked it. I created index.html in another path and add conf file to appache2 and bind another subdomains to this

Comment: solved your problem?

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani no, still not. I'm reading aobut nginx, but need some idea

Comment: email to me for more information.